# Trying to detect time of maximum of each pulse

Tags: arduino

Hi I am trying to write a code that is able to read the peak value of an analog sensor over time. 
Function needed is explained in image attached.
This is the code i have so far but it doesn't seem to work. Would appreciate some guidance on this. Thanks!

```
const int sensorpin1= A0;
int sensorvalue1=0;
int Max1=0;
unsigned long time1=0;
int thres=150;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {   
  sensorvalue1 = analogRead(sensorpin1);
  if(sensorvalue1 > Max1) {
    Max1= sensorvalue1;
    time1=millis();
  }
  if(sensorvalue1<=thres && Max1 > thres)  {
    Serial.print(Max1);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(time1);

    Max1=0;
  }
}
```

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gztNs.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhEX3.png)

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "doesn't seem to work".  Are you receiving an error?  Incorrect results?  etc.

Comment: your code does not even compile what is Max1.millis() supposed to do? Max1 is an integer.

Comment: @Piglet i want to get the time of the maximum at each pulse (time at Max1).

Comment: remove that time stuff. you did not even manage to get close to what the text describes. so why add more complications? try to implement the peak detection first. what is that for loop good for? why do you need that array? what happens to `sensorvalue1 <Max1` if you do `Max1 = sensorvalue1`?? do you realize that you only read that value once and then try to do some peak detection on that single reading?

Comment: @Piglet alright i will remove the time. I am using array to store each peak in each index so that each peak value can be used for further analysis. As for peak detection, do you have any examples of how the code should be? Sry but i am kind of new to coding arduino

Comment: maybe update your question with some improved code. I have no idea how you get from the text to your code. and I don't want to write 1 page about what you screwed up. please give it another thought. you can do what is in the text withn the main loop. no need for arrays, for loops and all that. once you have that working you can add times or store found peaks.

Comment: @Piglet This is my editted code that is can calculate the peak value of each peak. [Image of my arduino code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh5Nq.png)                       If i would like to save each peak value and the time of each peak, will i have to add in arrays and the usage of for loop? Appreciate your comment!

Comment: just read the time every time you store a new peak value. then when you report the peak, you have the time of that peak in that variable and you can send it with the peak via Serial. I don't see a reason for another loop or arrays, unless you want to store it on the Arduino as well.

Comment: @Piglet this is because eventually i will want to read peak values from 2 different sensors in 1 arduino board and compare the time difference between both peaks. so for example time difference of 1st peak of both sensors, time difference of 2nd peak of both sensors etc. so is there a need for arrays or can i jus do that in the normal void loop function

Comment: I edited your code according to that image. (And fixed a typo). If it still _doesn't seem to work_ (after peer review), please be more specific about your complaint. (Is it about your fixed threshold?)
For your two sensors problem you better start a new question :)

Comment: @datafiddler thanks for your comment! is it possible for me to change time1 to `time1= Max1.millis();` for the time of each peak?

Comment: If your original question "How to detect a max value" is answered, start a new one like "How to get time between two events, which cannot be detected immediately" or similar, and show how far you came yourself.

Comment: @datafiddler i was not able to detect the maximum value of each pulse. The `Serial.print(Max1)` is working more of an analog read of the sensor values where all the analog values are shown in the serial monitor instead of jus showing the maximum value.

Comment: @datafiddler Also i am getting Max1 values of 0 (which is not a peak value), does that mean it is not functioning as expected?

Comment: @baddieskater: You're right. It should only print out Max1, when it before exceeded `thres` and then returned below `thres`. Wait for peer review and see your edited code.